# How to pass and keep global variable remain unchanged in function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, function, variables

I am new to React. I am trying to import the variable from constants file and use it in function. Here's my demo code. However, if I call the function multiple times, the countries in `otherCountryList` just keep appending to the `COUNTRY_LIST`. How can I prevent this happen and everytime I call the function it will just append on `COUNTRY_LIST` as new list ?

Constants.js:

```
export const COUNTRY_LIST = ['USA', 'UK', 'SPAIN'];
```

index.js

```
import {COUNTRY_LIST} from './constants/constant';  
inputCountry(){
  let countryList = COUNTRY_LIST;
  //let say pushing other country to the countryList 
  for (var c = 0; c < this.otherCountryList.length; c ++){
    countryList.push(c);
  }
  console.log(countryList) //expected output:['USA', 'UK', 'SPAIN', 'AUS', 'JAPAN']
  // real output after called this function twice:['USA', 'UK', 'SPAIN', 'AUS', 'JAPAN', 'AUS', 'JAPAN']
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
const countryList = [...COUNTRY_LIST];
```

That's it, no push or for loop or anything else. It just copies the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got an error msg "_constants_constant__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__.COUNTRY_LIST is not iterable". Besides, if I use const to declare countryList, how can I push value to it in for-loop?

Comment: WRT the question, const does *not* mean you can't modify the array (a common misconception), only that you can't reassign the value. You can push to it, but you can't do something like `COUNTRY_LIST=[]`.

Comment: As for the error, it might be that your browser is not supporting the spread operator? You could try COUNTRY_LIST.slice() instead. console.log COUNTRY_LIST to check it's imported properly, though from your original error, you'd expect it is.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using const isn't work, but var works fine and solved my problem.